# CSS Sprite - position to right of input?

Tags: css, sprite

I'm trying to get  an input to load a **CSS sprite**, and put the icon I want out of it, right at the END of the input. Here is what I have so far:

```
#test2 {
    width: 140px;
    outline:0;
    background: url(http://www.chambresdhotes.org/new_design/sprites-all.png) -87px -97px no-repeat;
}
```

Here is some code I have that works fine, but it uses an individual image (this is what is currently live, but we want to convert it into a sprite for SEO);

```
#test1  {
    width: 140px;
    background-image:url(http://www.chambresdhotes.org//new_design/bookings/images/calendar1.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:95% center;
    outline:0;
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle to see the 2 running alongside each other:

https://jsfiddle.net/vr5emuar/

Can anyone explain where I'm going wrong? I've even tried using *:after* on the input (but it seems that doesn't work, as you can't use *:before* or *:after* on inputs)

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430981/using-a-sprite-image-with-input

Comment: Do you want display calendar icon alone at out side of the input box.

Comment: @Ezhil-UIDeveloper - I want to have it inside the *input*  (like the first example in my jsfiddle). It seems I can't do that though if I want to use a CSS sprite :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`::after` and `::before` are pseudo-elements and an input can't have element inside it.

There are multiple solutions :

- If you use css sprite, your sprite should be vertical and icons must be separated with some transparents pixel to avoid others icons to be visible in the input.
- Use a span or i element around the input, it generate icon with pseudo-element (`:after`) and put it over the input with absolute positionning on :after and relative position on the span.

Comment: Thanks - will give that a go. I was trying to avoid making a wrapper element around it, but it sounds like thats going to be the only option :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below only change needed is your sprite should be vertical.

```css
 

.input {border:none; float:left;padding:1px; outline: 0;}
.calander{
    border:1px solid #efefef;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    background: url(http://www.chambresdhotes.org/new_design/sprites-all.png)  no-repeat scroll 85px -94px  #fff;
    width:190px;
   padding: 4px 4px 6px 0px
   
}
```

```html
    
<div class="calander"><input type="text" class="input" /></div>
```